# Не находит элемент Selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

мой код:

```py
def get_data(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("user-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Redki_Maslin\Desktop\pars\2sait\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element("xpath","svg[@class='accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16']").click()
        time.sleep(120)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

ошибка:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"svg[@class='accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16']"}(Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)

код сайта:

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16"><path d="M10 8l4.5 4.5L10 17" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round"></path></svg>
```

Нужно найти этот элемент и нажать на него.
Пробовал ставить задержку, добавил user-agent, но это ничего не дало.
Cам сайт: https://pro.yandex.ru/ru-ru/moskva/knowledge-base/taxi/common/parks

кусок html:[image]

Comment: Никто не поможет без урла сайта. Кто знает откуда вы взяли кусок хтмл. Может из "исходный код страницы", а там в рантайме 100500 всего навешивается на это место. А может еще какая причина, но это уже телепатия нужна.

Comment: Вообще то xpath нужно начинать с // иначе он не пойдет искать вглубь.  А попробуйте `//*[name()='svg'][@class='accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16']`. В Firefox выбирает только `//*[name()='svg']`, но то файрфокс, а у вас в хроме может выбирает и так, но вы забыли //

Answer (score 0):

нужно было сменить

```
 driver.find_element("xpath","svg[@class='accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16']").click()
```

на

```
driver.find_element("xpath","//*[name()='svg'][@class='accordion_icon__t2NF8 margin-left-16']").click()
```

спасибо комментатору))